# Enabling multi type of requestbody in springboot based on type

Tags: java, spring-boot

i have a post request with requestbody, how can i enabling both type, string and object based on the enum type?

example sending string field

```
 "prencible": {
        "type": "naming",
        "value": "alex"
        
    },
```

example sending object field

```
 "prencible": {
        "type": "complex",
        "value": {
"firstnames": [
                "alex", "alex2"
            ],
            "lastnames": [
                "john", "john2"
            ]

}
        
    },
```

the type is enum has only
naming AND complex values

how can i implement a dto class for prencible which has
once

```
Prencible{
type = complex ;
PrencibleComplex; // here it has two attributes array 

}
```

and can also be

```
Prencible{
type = naming;
String value; // simply string

}
```

Comment: Please just don't do that. It's not a good practice. If you must then just take it as object and cast it with ```instanceof String/YourClass```

Comment: could you give me an example of how to do that

Comment: imo, you should create two different APIs & DTOs to accept the string & object.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that this function is your controller, so it accepts requests

**Don't use this, this is bad**

```
void processVeryBadIdea(Request request) {
    Prencible prencible = request.getBody();
    
    switch (prencible.getType()){
        case naming:
           processSimpleData((String) prencible.getValue());
        case complex:
           processComplexData((PrencibleComplex) prencible.getValue());
    }
}
```

You can do it like that, but it's also the worst idea you can have.

**You should create 2 controller functions each for each request type that you want to handle. You can have shared logic inside. But don't do this. This just hurts when you want to use api like that.**

Comment: is it possible to do so using jackson?

Comment: from what i know it's not possible and it shouldnt be